# How to delete files in a specific subfolder?

Tags: batch-file, filesystems

So far I have tried this:

```
For /R "C:\Test\" %%G IN (*.*) do del "%%G"
```

With this code it deletes all files starting from `c:\test\` but I want to delete files on a specific subfolder.

Any suggestions?

Comment: and whats the problem to change  "C:\Test\" to  "C:\Test\subfolder"?

Comment: `del /q "c:\test\subfolder\*"`? or, `del /q /s "c:\test\subfolder\*"`? What are we missing?

Comment: i'll give you a bit more information, i have a test folder, in that folder there are 10 userfolders, within each userfolder there is a download folder, i need the script to look for the user download folders without having to manually add the subfolder for every user.
If i add a new user it has to automatically go to that persons dowload folder and empty it.

Answer (score 0):

This will delete the visible files from one folder.

```
For %%G in ("C:\Test\subfolder\*.*") do del "%%G"
```

Answer (score 0):

The del command accepts path and wildcard parameters, if you dont do anything else in that loop you can change it to

```
del C:\Test\subfolder\*.*
```